# Center Seaborn Colorbar Labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm looking at discrete data, but the colorbars in seaborn look like they're only set up for continuous variables.

My code produces the chart I want, but the labels on the colorbar don't line up with their respective colors.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,6,size=(52, 7)))
colors = {0:'#05926f', 1:'#99cc33', 2:'#F26419', 3:'#F6AE2D', 4:'#06AED5', 5:'#3baa5d'}
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(list(colors.values()))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,8))
ax = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, cmap=cmap, linewidths=.05)
plt.plot()
```

<s>I've tried adding `cbar_kws={"anchor": (0.5, 0.5)}` as a argument to the sns.heatmap call, but it throws an error saying it doesn't like the anchor keyword. But the [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) says I should be able to use arguments from [pyplot.colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html), but no luck.</s>Nevermind, see comment below.

I'm not sure how to center that label. Am I missing something obvious?

I'd also like to change the labels from `#` to `Group-#` if there's an easy solution to that.

Thank you!

Comment: "anchor" has nothing to do with the colors or labels, it is the position of the colorbar. Unless you want to change the position, there is no reason trying to use that argument. Concerning the actual problem, what exactly do you want your plot to look like?

Comment: Hmm. The numbers on the side of the colorbar (0-6 in this case) are aligned for continuous data (i.e. 0 at the very bottom, and 6 at the very top). I want the numbers to be centered directly next to the colors they represent in the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a boundary norm. The problem is that matplotlib would not know which value you want to have corresponding to which color. To give this information, a `BoundaryNorm` can be used, specifying the bin edges of the colors. As in this example you have the integers `0,1,2,3,4,5` as the values, your bin edges are best chosen to be `-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5`, such that the values lie in the center of the bins.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
#%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,6,size=(52, 7)))
colors = {0:'#05926f', 1:'#99cc33', 2:'#F26419', 3:'#F6AE2D', 4:'#06AED5', 5:'#3baa5d'}

colorrange = range(len(list(colors.keys())))
colorlist = [colors[i] for i in colorrange]
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colorlist)
bounds = np.array(range(len(list(colors.keys()))+1))-0.5
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, len(colorrange))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4.2,8))
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
ax = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, 
                 cbar_kws={'format': 'Group-%g'}, linewidths=.05)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Code for when the data range does not start at 0, but is still N successive integers:

```css
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
#%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,7,size=(52, 7)))
colors = {6:'#05926f', 1:'#99cc33', 2:'#F26419', 3:'#F6AE2D', 4:'#06AED5', 5:'#3baa5d'}

colorrange = sorted(list(colors.keys()))
colorlist = [colors[i] for i in colorrange]
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colorlist)
bounds = np.array(colorrange+[max(colorrange)+1])-0.5
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, len(colorrange))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4.2,8))
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
ax = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, 
                 cbar_kws={'format': 'Group-%g'}, linewidths=.05)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: for the 'format': 'Group-%g' section, what if the groups numbering doesn't start at 0. e.g. np.random.randint(1, 7, size=(52, 7))?

Comment: I added the solution for this case to the answer. You would need to change your dictionary and the lists, but the format stays the same.